# Como mockar uma classe inexistente com Rspec Mock

Tags: ruby, rspec, mock

Estou criando uma `lib` que irá utilizar um `model` padrão do `Rails`, só que para o desenvolvimento dessa `lib` eu preciso testar sem a presença desse `model`.

Pensem então em mockar (estou utilizar a gem [rspec-mock](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks)), tentei assim:

```
it '#user_autenticated?' do
  allow('User').to receive(:where).and_return([double('User', cpf: '00011122233344')])

  auth = Rbot::Auth.new(maestro)
  expect(auth.user_autenticated?).not_to be nil
end
```

Mas infelizmente recebo o erro:

```
"User" does not implement: where
```

Alguém sabe uma saída para esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que dê para fazer de várias formas, mas para o seu caso que precisa de um método do ActiveRecord, a melhor opção seria o `mock_model`.

Algo como:

```
user = mock_model(User)
allow(user).to receive(:where).and_return([double('User', cpf: '00011122233344')])
```

Ou se já estiver usando FactoryGirl

```
FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user)
```

Este post contém mais detalhes: https://www.agileventures.org/articles/testing-with-rspec-stubs-mocks-factories-what-to-choose